# How to conduct a proper comparison between systems using SVM with RBF kernel?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm, hyperparameters

When comparing systems using SVM with RBF kernel, should we use the same C and gamma (fixed values, for example C=10, gamma=0.1) for all the systems or do hyperparameter turning and choose the best values of C and gamma for each system?

Comment: What are "systems"? What are you comparing?

Comment: I am building a text classification system and would like to compare the performance of different text classification systems.

Comment: If these systems consists of different input-data to sour SVMs, of course you would use per-system based parameter optimization. The optimal params of one systems is not necessarily the best for some other (with very high probability). This is due to the fact, that hyper-param opt is always dependent on the data.

Answer (score 0):

As #sascha wrote, Different classifiers can train better with different parameters.

But it's OK. for different tasks you also have different requirement. If, for example you invented a new classification algorithm, and want to compare it with the state-of-the-art for a specific task, usually there will already be an optimized code for the specific task you are trying to learn, so you will only need to make small refinements to your own algorithm. On the other hand, if you have a new task, and just want to try out different classifiers, you will need to play with the both of them, until getting to some plateau. If there were big differences between the algorithms, take the one which gave you higher performance, and from than you can play only with it. If both of them gave you similar results, you have two options:

1. Make small adjustments to both of them until you get to a satisfy result
2. Try out other algorithms